# I need to place a block or image for bundle product alone in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need to place a static block or image below the breadcrumbs in all bundle product pages.

How to achieve this.Help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding below code in appropriate view file. and make sure `$_product` variable is available in that view file.

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'bundle' ): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_id')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :
-1st when creating a bundle product in "Design" section, in "Custom Layout Update" add

```
<reference name="product.info"><action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/viewbundle.phtml</template></action></reference>
```

-Then in the template add your static block like this :

```
<div class="class1">
<p><?php echo Mage::helper('yourmodule')->getStaticBlock('staticBlockId')?></p>
</div>
```

Here the implementation of the method getStaticBlock :

```
/**
* @param string $blockId
* @param string $class
*/
public static function getStaticBlock($blockId, $class = '') {
  if (Mage::app ()->getLayout ()->createBlock ( 'cms/block' )->setBlockId ( $blockId )->toHtml ()) {
    return '<div class="static-block ' . $class . '">' . Mage::app ()->getLayout ()->createBlock ( 'cms/block' )->setBlockId ( $blockId )->toHtml () . '</div>';
  }
  return '';
}
```